# how can i remove user from nexus api?

Tags: api, maven, plugins, nexus, sonatype

I am trying for few days to create some API automation for Sonatype nexus 3.0.0. I successfully created scripts to create role, repository, user. But I am stuck on removing them.

I found lot of old documentation (nexus 2.x.x) but nothing actual,

I tried to add methods in `internal/SecurityApiImpl.groovy` and `void deleteUser(String id, String sourceId)`; in 
`org.sonatype.nexus.security.SecurityApi` but when I try to test it i stuck on

```
{
  "name" : "removeUser",
  "result" : "javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.sonatype.nexus.security.internal.SecurityApiImpl.deleteUser() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [cosik, default]"
}
```

Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 1):

I just created similar scripts. Try something like this for delete users with the default nexus realm. Pass the user as a json object. Currently works for me.

```
{
    "id": "bob1234"
}

import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def sourceId = 'default'
def user = new JsonSlurper().parseText(args)
security.securitySystem.deleteUser(user.id, sourceId)
return groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(user)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for "nexus groovy delete role" and I find only this SO post on "delete user"... in case you want to delete a Role, you must invoke :

import static org.sonatype.nexus.security.user.UserManager.DEFAULT_SOURCE

security.securitySystem.getAuthorizationManager(DEFAULT_SOURCE).deleteRole(id)

Unfortunately the Nexus Groovy and Java APIs are quite inconsistent.